# Facing issue in User Defined Function of Azur SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write User Defined Function which ***input string is a\b\c***, and the function will give me ***out put as  L1 L2 L3 (column name/header)
a  b  c(row values)***

The issue I am facing:

[image]

1. Table value function is giving me error
2. Table variable also giving me error

Comment: You just need to put `GO` between your alter function statement, and your statement that calls the function to make them separate batches. When running in the same batch it makes it all appear as one statement and creates a syntax error. There is no issue with your actual function - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=372e18595d049028470dc0f38071d1f2

Comment: Also, [please don't post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1048425), you should post the actual SQL as text.

Comment: If you need the value split into columns, and you have a dynamic number of columns then you won't be able to do this with a function, as a function must have a fixed number of columns.